# I have an iOS 6 App I've been building not yet in the app store but I'd like it to be separate from the iOS 7 app?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7

I read this article/saw a few posts about [App Store Backwards Compatibility](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2013/09/17/apple-begins-allowing-users-running-legacy-ios-builds-to-download-older-versions-of-apps/) but unfortunately my app is not yet in the app store.  My company would like a new look for iOS7 to go along with the new styles but doesn't want the time spent on autolayout/tweaking iOS6. Is there a way (without having two separate projects/apps) that I can upload a build for just iOS6 (and no longer work on that project - i.e. it's legacy) and then submit an iOS7 version so that users not yet on 7 will see the alert box letting them know they have to use 7 or they can use an older compatible version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you haven't released yet, just target iOS 7...

Comment: My company builds services for people who are sometimes locked in and cannot upgrade so iOS6 is a requirement. Hence my question as I'm curious to see if my only option is now build for 6 and 7 and use separate storyboards (I imagine that's possible).

Comment: If all you're going to do on iOS 6 is display an alert saying the user needs to use iOS 7 then Apple isn't going to be happy with that (and neither are the users). You should build an app that runs properly on both 6 & 7.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't think you're getting what I'm saying at all... Look at the link, or read the post, don't just comment, I'm quite clear when I say I want a FULL separate app for both.

Comment: That feature doesn't allow you to release the app for old versions, it just allows users to (re)download old versions if the current version doesn't support their OS. So, it's a dead end solution because you can't make any updates to the old version. You could release one version for 6 and as soon as it goes live release the 7 version, then continue on with 7 alone.

Comment: Ah, well then if that is true then I'll have to design one to work for both 6 and 7, if you move that comment to an answer I'll give it a thumbs up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new feature from Apple doesn't allow you to release the app for old versions, it just allows users to (re)download old versions if the current version doesn't support their OS. So, it's a dead end solution because you can't make any updates to the old version. You also need to consider what effect this has in terms of your webservices that the app uses and things like that - can they be turned off if users are still using an old version of the app that you intended to stop supporting.

You could release one version for 6 and as soon as it goes live release the 7 version, then continue on with 7 alone. But it's better to either explicitly start from 7 alone or to build an app that fully support both 6 & 7.

Comment: New question similar but different enough that I want people to be able to easily find it. This is for an application I already have had in the app store for several iterations - http://tinyurl.com/kaxdtrl